# Django Management command for Activating/Deactivating admin site

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I would like to know if it's possible to *'Activate'* and *'Deactivate'* the admin site using a custom management command and what i mean by deactivating is commenting the line containing the path of **admin.site.urls** in the main **urls.py** file.
Or if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do it - write custom middleware.
You can detect if current request is request to admin site (for example `request.path.startswith('/admin')`) and return 404 error if you disable you admin page.

Comment: and how do you suggest we control it in production (the activation / deactivation) part ? can we use custom management command or the admin site itself ?

Comment: You should create some model in database for store live configuration. Add item with key named like ADMIN_SITE_ENABLED with True/False value. Every time, when you middleware detect request to /admin pages you need make request to database and check you current config and return 404 error if you config is False. Only tat you need after this - create custom management command for on/off config item in database.

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to deactivate the admin urls? For example if you want to deactivate admin site urls for production, you can add a control to urls.py checkin if settings.DEBUG is False.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        path('basic-admin/', basic_site.urls)
    ]
```

Comment: what I'm trying to create is a command i can use (in production) to activate AND deactivate the admin site, example if i want to use the admin interface i just ssh into the server and execute the command and the admin site will be available after that i can deactivate it using another command (or the same command with different argument )